# Get link from href querying the text inside its parent tag

Tags: html, regex, typescript

I have the follwing element

```
<a href="https://domain.domain/appointment/confirm?id=7254&amp;token=token&amp;locale=nl-NL" target="_blank"\r\n                                   style="text-decoration: none;
 font-size: 16px; font-weight: 300; line-height: 24px;
 font-family: Next W1G, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #ffffff;">bevestigen</a>^
```

I want to get the link inside the `href` where the text contained in `a` tag is `bevestigen`

I have tried

```
<a\s+(?:[^>]*?\s+)?href=(["'])(.*?)bevestigen<\/a>
```

but I am not getting the clean Url

Comment: Try it like this and get the value from capture group 2 `<a\s[^>]*href=(["'])([^]*?)\1[^>]*>bevestigen<\/a>` https://regex101.com/r/YzXO6R/1 You could also use the DOM to get the anchor and the src attribute where the element value is bevestigen.

Comment: Did it work out?

Comment: I have used /<a [^>]*\bhref\s*=\s*"([^"]*bevestigen[^"]*)/gs